# Bash: Reading files with defined file extensions in a loop

Tags: bash

While this code works

```
#!/bin/bash
d="test_files/*"
for f in $d.{mp3,txt} ;do
do something 
done
```

putting the {mp3,txt} in to a variable does not, see code below.

```
#!/bin/bash
a={mp3,txt}
d="test_files/*"
for f in $d."$a" ;do
do smoething
done
```

the output here is /*.{mp3,txt}

Putting {mp3,txt} in to an array

```
a=({mp3,txt})
```

outputs only files with the *.mp3 extension.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The second example fails because brace expansion occurs prior to parameter expansion, so the braces are treated literally. The third example fails because `a` is an array of two elements, and `$a` expands to only the first (it's equivalent to `${a[0]}`).

Comment: Remove the quotation marks around "$a". They stop bash from expanding the braces.

When you have an array "a" then "$a" will evaluate to the first item. For all items use "${a[@]}".

Also: read "man bash"

Comment: Using the "${a[@]}" in the loop "for f in $d.${a[@]}", fails all so.

Comment: It iterates $d.$a[0], giving me the all the mp3 files. on a[1], the out put is just "txt". I solved it with 2 for loop, the first iterating the "$a" array and the second iterating "$d" argument.
Still if anybody has any ideas how to do this with one loop, i'm still interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because brace expansion happens before all other expansions.

From `man bash`:

> Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, and any
>   characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result. It
>   is strictly textual. Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation
>   to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces. To
>   avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string ‘${’ is not
>   considered eligible for brace expansion

You can use `eval` to do brace expansion stored in variables, but it is not recommended. For example:

```
eval echo "$d.$a"
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, the tutorial i'm using did not mention brace expansion.